# "Could not find OneDriveSetup.exe" CMD error when Windows 10 start-up

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, onedrive

While I did not ask the question in Microsoft Community, the situation is identical as in this [Microsoft Community link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/could-not-find-onedrivesetupexe/e65b8bd3-7957-4826-8a5d-39fb649ecb29). When Windows 10 starts up, it pops up a CMD window that shows "Could not find .....OneDriveSetup.exe" then the window disappears.

What should I do to resolve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Edit your question to indicate what version of Windows 10 you are using.  Knowing the exact build your using would also be helpful.

Comment: If you have the identically problem then it’s caused by the scheduled task that runs the standalone OneDrive updater.  If you remove that scheduled task, the behavior will stop, since the current version of OneDrive is already installed.  Provide the necessary information from Autoruns to formulate an answer.